# Answering a question privately (or send a private message to the OP)

Tags: discussion, answers

Based on [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50471/hiring-a-driver-with-a-car-in-tbilisi-for-a-day), I may be able to help the OP, as I have a personal recommendation for somebody that specialises in this.  Yet this is a private person, not a company or agency, and I wouldn't want to post the person's phone number in a publicly available answer.

Is there a way to answer the question privately?  So that only the OP sees the answer?  I guess, in other words, is there a way to send a private/personal message to the OP?

Comment: Yes ! I was looking for a way to contact you directly about this as well as I may be going to Georgia this year

Comment: @Blackbird57 In my profile description, at the bottom, I included my email address - email me directly and I'll reply.

Comment: I have had this on occasion:  http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3130/reverse-google-encounters

Answer (score 2):

You can always [create a new (private) chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=travel.stackexchange.com) between people only you decide to invite to, rather than the main chat room.

Comment: Is the chat room really private?

Comment: Yes, you can exclude everyone else. Mods do it occasionally to deal with thorny issues.

Comment: Ah, [might be just for mods](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143641/why-are-there-private-chat-options)

Comment: Private chatrooms are indeed a special feature reserved for official mod business. The best a normal user can do is a gallery room, where only certain users may talk but anyone on the Internet can still read.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can send private message to the OP. You can however invite them in a chat room to discuss the topic. If you want to keep things private you could always ask the OP for their private contact details. That would in my opinion be the best way to go about it. The obvious flaw here is that the OP must have enough reputation to be able to access the chat.

Of course you want to avoid being accused of spam, since the same rules apply in the chat: hidden/undisclosed advertising is not allowed. However being an experienced user it's clear that your sole intent is not to pitch a product on SE.

Comment: I'm not worried about being accused of spamming - but rather the opposite - I don't want to post a personal phone number of somebody that helped me in the past in an open forum.

Comment: @AleksG Yup I got that. I just wanted to add the spam clause in there to be safe. ;)

Comment: No worries, I understand.